# Open animated plot in new window

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, x11, gganimate

I'm new to R and I'm a bit lost.

I have a code:

```
jpg <- (
xyplot(
  USD + EUR ~ data,
  data = ret,
  type = "l",
  ylab = "GBP",
  xlab = "month",
  key = list(space = "right",
             columns = 1,
             text = list(c("EUR", "USD")),
             rectangles = list(col = c("pink", "green")), 
             cex = 0.7))
)
x11()
print(jpg)
```

and thanks for it I can open my plot automatically in new window.
I would like to do the same with this code:

```
levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))
levels(factor(mtcars$gear))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 

  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out') + 
  labs(title = 'Fuel consumption for {closest_state} gears', x = 'cyl')

anim_save("mtcars.gif")
```

, but I don't know how. How can I do it using x11()?

Answer (score 0):

In R you can use the "<-" operator to create an object with your code.

In the first lines, they use "jpg <- ...." to assign the xyplot to the object name "jpg" then they use the "print" function to visualize it.

I'm not sure what your "anim_save("mtcars.gif")" is for but for the lines above that, you could you try:

```
levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))
levels(factor(mtcars$gear))

CARPLOT <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 

  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out') + 
  labs(title = 'Fuel consumption for {closest_state} gears', x = 'cyl')

print (CARPLOT)
```

For the .gif, you could also assign that to an object to visualize it.